Cannot perform Merge: multiple source rows matched in Delta Table
I am facing an issue while performing a MERGE operation on my Delta table. The error message I receive is:

Cannot perform Merge as multiple source rows matched and attempted to
modify the same target row in the Delta table in possibly conflicting
ways.

I have verified that there are no duplicates in the primary key of my target table.
Data Insertion: Initially, I inserted some input data successfully.
However, when I attempt to insert the same data again, I get this error.
Here’s a simplified version of the SQL code I am using for the MERGE operation:
MERGE INTO target_table AS t
USING source_table AS s
ON t.primary_key = s.primary_key
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t.column1 = s.column1, t.column2 = s.column2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (primary_key, column1, column2) VALUES (s.primary_key, s.column1, s.column2)

What could cause multiple source rows to match the same target row, even when there are no duplicates in my primary key?
How can I preprocess the source data to prevent this issue?

Just run SELECT PRIMARY_KEY, COUNT(1) FROM SOURCE_TABLE GROUP BY PRIMARY_KEY HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 to identify the duplicates in your source. It’s up to you how you then deal with these duplicates: if each set of duplicates has the same value in every field you could use SELECT DISTINCT, otherwise you’d need to decide which records to eliminate or how to combine the records into a single record

Either the source table or the target table has duplicates; i.e. the column called primary_key is not actually the primary key in one or both tables.

If the duplicates are only in the source table, you can add a cte (WITH) to redefine the source as a subquery removing duplicates)
